# RGL colored legend

Tags: r, legend, rgl

I tried this program:

```
library(rgl)  
palette(rainbow(7))  
s3d <- with(df, plot3d(x, y, z, col=type, radius=0.2, type="s"))  
legend3d("topright", col=levels(df$type), legend=levels(df$type), cex=1)
```

To better understand, here are some lines of my dataframe "df":

```
      x  y  z type
9249 -2 10 10    5
9250 -1 10 10    5
9251  0 10 10    4
9252  1 10 10    4
9253  2 10 10    4
9254  3 10 10    4
9255  4 10 10    4
9256  5 10 10    1
9257  6 10 10    3
9258  7 10 10    3
```

(actually, the variable "type" is a factor having **7** levels)

Well, I got an OK plot with a legend boxed in the topright part, but no color matching the levels 1 to 7 indicated in the legend box...

[image]
I am surely missing something with my "col=" instructions, but what ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You haven't told the `legend()` function (which is called by `legend3d()`) to plot anything.  Add `pch = 16` (or some other symbol number) and you'll get a better result.

Comment: Oh my god! Shame on me. Thank you so much.